# Deleted terraform resource manually unable to delete the resource using terraform code

Tags: terraform

We have deleted terraform resource manually. We wanted to delete the resource from terraform code as well and update the state file but when I am trying to delete the resource using terraform code I am getting "resourceId not present" error.  Is there a way I can remove the resource from the state file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [terraform state rm](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/state/rm):

> Terraform will search the state for any instances matching the given resource address, and remove the record of each one so that Terraform will no longer be tracking the corresponding remote objects.

Comment: There are many objects inside our project like gke cluster,cloudsql etc., we manually deleted only our project. Now if I remove the project from the state file using the rm command, can I be able to delete gke cluster, cloudsql etc., using the terraform code?

Comment: @explorer Not sure what you mean. But if you remove them from state file, then you have to remove them from the source code. Otherwise TF will try to create them again.

Comment: I meant we have manually just deleted one project in GCP and there are many associated objects(like cloudsql etc) inside that project. After removing the project from the state file using rm command, will I be able to delete associated objects(cloudsql etc) using terraform config files(main.tf etc)?

Comment: @explorer I'm not sure. You can always create some dummy tf project, and verify how it works in your scenario.

Comment: just comment out the resources that you want to delete and let terraform update the state for you when you run a terraform plan

Comment: @Darren I tried to delete the associated objects by commenting but I am getting 
"projects is empty list of object" error. I think it is because we have already deleted the project manually.